# Bower not getting installed

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I am trying to use npm to install bower (with -g or without -g) but unable to do so. The installing wheel just keeps rotating for continuously but nothing gets installed.

I tried looking for help online but nobody seems to have had this issue before.

1. Tried npm cache clean, didn't help.
2. Manually cleared bower folders and lock in the ~/.npm folder.

Node version -- 0.12.0
npm version -- 2.5.1
OS - Yosemite

After a really long wait, I got the following error. My internet is working and neither am I behind a proxy.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jayesh/npm-debug.log
```

Logs after running with verbose 
    npm info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm verb cli [ '/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node',
    npm verb cli   '/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm',
    npm verb cli   'install',
    npm verb cli   '-g',
    npm verb cli   'bower',
    npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
    npm info using npm@2.5.1
    npm info using node@v0.12.0
    npm verb cache add spec bower
    npm verb addNamed bower@*
    npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/bower not in flight;         fetching
    npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
    npm verb request no auth needed
    npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 1:14:03 AM
    npm verb request id 42efd554bb50b061
    npm verb etag "BP1YZKBGAIE38MKI0RCNK8G2H"
    npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
    npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/bower from cache
    npm verb get saving bower to     /Users/jayesh/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/bower/.cache.json
    npm verb addNamed bower@1.3.12
    npm verb afterAdd /Users/jayesh/.npm/bower/1.3.12/package/package.json not in     flight; writing
    npm verb afterAdd /Users/jayesh/.npm/bower/1.3.12/package/package.json written
    npm info install bower@1.3.12 into /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib
    npm info installOne bower@1.3.12
    npm verb installOne of bower to /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib     not in flight; installing
    npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/jayesh/.npm/_locks/bower-990c3d8ae8803e10.lock'
    npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
    npm WARN locking  /Users/jayesh/.npm/_locks/bower-990c3d8ae8803e10.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/jayesh/.npm/_locks/bower-990c3d8ae8803e10.lock']
    npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
    npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
    npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/jayesh/.npm/_locks/bower-990c3d8ae8803e10.lock' }
    npm verb stack Error: Attempt to unlock /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/bower, which hasn't been locked
    npm verb stack     at unlock (/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:66:11)
    npm verb stack     at cb (/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:929:5)
    npm verb stack     at /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:933:20
    npm verb stack     at /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:40:9
    npm verb stack     at cb (/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:149:38)
    npm verb stack     at /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:177:38
    npm verb stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
    npm verb cwd /Users/jayesh/sandeep/valueaddnew
    npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
    npm ERR! argv "/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower" "--verbose"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.0
    npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

```
npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /Users/jayesh/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/bower, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request
```

Comment: Try install with `--verbose` option and let me know the output: `$ npm install -g bower --verbose`

Comment: Hi devxoul, what can be inferred from the log is that the lock is placed at a different location while during installation it tries to find in a different location and find that the lock is not placed and hence waits and throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set correct permissions (ownership) so `npm` can access your directories with your own user permissions:

```
chown -R $USER <directory>
```

where in your case `<directory>` is `/Users/jayesh`.

[See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787215/1614973).